# Javascript TypeError states a list is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I created a function which receives a list as input and then operates on that list:

```
function selected_items(list) {
    for (i=0;i<=list.length;i++){
        item = list[i].split("-");
        item_id = item[0] + '-' + item[1] + '-' + item[2]
        user_id = item[4]
        $('#shift_data_' + user_id).children('#' + item_id).toggleClass('selected')
    }
}
```

The list is composed by some strings like this : ["a-b-c", "a1-b1-c1", etc.]

I want to process the strings one by one, split them after the operator "-" and then do some work on that to help me select some items in the DOM.

The funny part is that the code works as expected however in the console I get
the following error:

```
 TypeError: list[i] is undefined
    --> item = list[i].split("-");
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error even though the code is working?

Comment: Please show your code for when you call your `selected_items()` function. Your error is because you're not passing something into your function's `list` argument.

Comment: [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) _JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1._

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much for the answer. I replaced the "i" in the <for> with 1 and the list[i] becomes list[i-1] now. The error is gone and the code works!

Comment: @Soviut I simply do "selected_items(list)" where list is an array created out of DOM id's pushed in there after clicking on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping the list out of range. Try changing this:

```
for (i=0; i<=list.length; i++){
```

by this:

```
for (i=0; i<=list.length - 1; i++){
```

or this:

```
for (i=0; i < list.length; i++){
```

Comment: Using `i < list.length` is more idiomatic.

Comment: I have modified my answer @Barmar. Thanks =D